# Host a website locally on ubuntu server 14.04 over wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, server, apache2, lamp

I have a web application which makes use of the LAMP installation.

Its currently hosted on amazon's ubuntu ec2 instance

Now we have to completely eliminate the use of internet.

For that we are setting up an Ubuntu Server 14.04 installation and have a WiFi router attached to it, so that users can connect to the server and use the web application.

Based on my research I understand the following things to need be done

- installing ubuntu server on the machine
- setting up a lamp stack

My question is:

1. How to access the apache server since ubuntu server doesn't have a gui or a browser?
2. How to make the server accessible over WiFi?

Thank you!

Comment: the server machine is on  a different network ( "and have a WiFi router attached to it")?. 
If so, it's not necessary, you just need to connect the server to your existing LAN, give it an static ip, then configure the virtual host for that ip on apache. 
For graphical access, you can install phpmyadmin to access mysql, or open port 3306 and access with any desktop database client. For files, if you dont like command line, you can access an ftp server and connect to it from filezilla or another ftp client.

Comment: @bistoco can you please elaborate .

Answer (score 3):

Your private network is for example 192.168.0.XXX (or [another range](https://kx.cloudingenium.com/infrastructure/networking-segments-private-network-segments/) )

- you connect your server (wifi or ethernet) to that network, and assign a [static ip address](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu) (one that won't change when router or machine is rebooted ), like 192.168.0.151.
- you need to [create a virtualhost](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) for that ip listening on port 80, and/or if you want to use a domain name, you must eventually install a dns server on your network or edit hosts file on client machine.
- Then you can access to your app on the brokser on http://192.168.0.115/pat/to/app (or with the domain name if you configured that)

For the graphical tools :

- install Phpmyadmin on the server to admin mysql databases, or open port 3306 to access with a desktop db client like dbvisualizer.
- install a ftp server (service) like [vsftpd](https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-set-up-an-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-1404-12301) on ubuntu server, and access it from the client with filezilla

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install LAMP is:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install tasksel

sudo tasksel
```

in the terminal you should now see the option to install lamp and ssh
use the spacebar to select and install the necessary components
you will be opted to configure a password for MySQL remember your password we will need it for the next part.

2)now that the terminal installation is complete let's make things easy to configure in MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

make sure to use the same password you set in part 1 of MySQL installation of lamp.
restart ubuntu and all services should be running.

3) downloading files from Amazon, .zip all web files on the host server and use wget to download the files to your new Ubuntu server
ex.)

```
cd /var/www/

wget http://yourdomain.com/site.zip

unzip site.zip
```

If this site is database driven simply go to your web browser and type:
http://ubuntu-server-ip-address/phpmyadmin
and import the database

You can use ssh to create or edit files currently on the server. If you prefer a GUI and you are using Windows find a program called datafreeway it is free and works great for gaining an interface as the root user